# jQuery document on submit from modal window to update mysql

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jQuery document on submit in a modal window to trigger a mysql update using a remote file.

Without the jQuery the form updates the database as required but obviously means navigating back to the original form from a success message on the remote file.

Using on submit I get the success message (and failure message) from within the form however doesn't update the database.

Php and jQuery aren't my strong points and I'm beyond my knowledge, though it may be something quite simple I've overlooked... it's been a long day!

Any thoughts much appreciate - apologies if I've done anything wrong here, 1st time posting after a few years of using this site.

```js
$(document).on("submit", "form#update-person", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  document.getElementById('form-body').innerHTML = 'PROCESSING MESSAGE HERE';

  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: $(this).attr('type'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(html) {
      document.getElementById('form-body').innerHTML = 'SUCCESS MESSAGE HERE;
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      document.getElementById('form-body').innerHTML = ' FAILURE MESSAGE HERE;
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form-body">
  <form id="update-person" name="update-person" method="post" action="/includes/update-process.php" type="post">
    Form content
    <input type="submit" id="update-submit"  name="update-submit" value="Update Person">
  </form>
</div> <!--/#form-body -->
```

Comment: Don't complicate it much. Just `$('form#update-person').on('submit', function(e) {});` would be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I'm trying to achieve is for the user to either stay on the modal with a success message (and option to close) while submit triggers the update without having the user ending up on /remote-file.php

Using your example the user would still end up on /remote-file.php

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That's not an example or solution I commented out. It's just a suggestion to write jQuery's form `onsubmit` event simpler.

Comment: I don't understand, do you get the success message or the error message? Both seems unlikely... And what does php return?

Comment: enable errors in the php file and then using dev tools on chomre open the network tab and when the call is made the php file will be loaded where you should be able to find the error another options is to edit the php file "/includes/update-process.php" use a try catch block to catch the exception error, json encode the error and return the encoded error. e.g. `try{ //pdo } catch(PDOException $e){ return json_encode([$e->getMessage()]); }` from the error on the javascript console you should be able to find why the data isnt being inserted into your database.

Comment: You want to display the success or failure message on modal dialog on the page upon form submitting. To simply put, you just want to display the message without navigating to another page displaying the success or failure message on the modal dialog itself. Right?

Comment: @Perumal93 `$(document).on("submit", "form#update-person", function (e) {` is fine, it will always work, even if the form is added to the page after the initial page load.

Comment: @jeroen I know it works. I've just given him a suggestion to write it simpler way.

Comment: @Perumal93 your suggestion will not work in this case since the form in the modal added dynamically to the DOM and need the event delegation..

Comment: In this case, the modal form is not dynamic. You could look at the OP's HTML code.

Comment: @jeroen I get the success message - if I pass in an invalid url or try to force an error I get the failure message.

Comment: But what does php return: The `html` variable in javascript or the response in the browser developer tools.

Comment: The html variable from javascript

Comment: I mean the contents of that variable...

Comment: I get this part - 'PROCESSING MESSAGE HERE'. 

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding - I can post links to site and files if easier?

Comment: Lot's of questions here, can you please post the PHP code? Also, most of the time when updating a database you should be using POST method. As it stands, the Ajax call here is defaulting to GET.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, with a fresh set of eyes I found the problem this morning. Within the PHP on the remote page was an if { } looking for a button submission. As this was being bypassed by the Ajax nothing was happening. All sorted and now working - Cheers